# Angular Material- Getting id from clicked row element

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I want to get row id and clicked element id when clicking on the button in the Angular Material table...

I got clicked element id but the row's id is not getting it shows `undefined`. How to get the id in the component?

HTML

```
<table     mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matTableResponsive>

  <!-- ID Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row let i=index;"> {{ i+1}} 

    </td>
  </ng-container>



  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Amount </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.amount}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="discount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Discount </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.discount}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="total">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.total}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="orderStatus">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Change Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 

      <button mat-button color="accent" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menustatus"> {{row.orderProcess.orderStatus}}</button></td> 

    <mat-menu  #menustatus="matMenu">
      <button  (click)="changestatus($event,row)" mat-menu-item [value]="os.id" *ngFor="let os of orderprocessing">{{os.name}}</button>

    </mat-menu>
  </ng-container> 

</table>
```

in the last column, I get the menu from API like this  `ordered,shipped` and so on...

Component

```js
changestatus(e:any,row:any)
{
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log(row);
}
```

In my second console, I get `undefined`.

How to get the id in the single onclick function?

Comment: if `row` would be undefined, then it would be not an error as console.log(undefined) is a valid statement

Comment: Can you provide sample JSON data? Meanwhile which `id` you want to get? `row.id` or `os.id`?

Comment: @YongShun i want to get row.id ......that os.id is order status id

Comment: @YongShun {
  
    "Data": [
        {
            "id": 1,    "amount": 510,  "discount": 10,  "total": 500,}
           ]

Comment: @YongShun  i put seperate loop for change status column this is json data for change status column "Data": [
        {  "id": 1,  "name": "Ordered"  },
        {  "id": 2, "name": "Packed"  }]

Comment: ok thank you so much its working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect from the above HTML code, look like you close `</td>` after the `mat-button` element.

Hence, the `row` value is not accessible for the `<mat-menu>` button as it is not within the `<td>` scope.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
                  
    <button mat-button color="accent" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menustatus"> {{row.orderProcess.orderStatus}}</button>
</td> 
              
    <mat-menu  #menustatus="matMenu">
        <button  (click)="changestatus($event,row)" mat-menu-item [value]="os.id" *ngFor="let os of orderprocessing">{{os.name}}</button>
               
   </mat-menu>
```

---

### Solution

Place `<mat-menu>` element within the `<td>` element.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <button mat-button color="accent" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menustatus">
    {{row.orderProcess.orderStatus}}
  </button>

  <mat-menu #menustatus="matMenu">
    <button
      (click)="changestatus($event,row)"
      mat-menu-item
      [value]="os.id"
      *ngFor="let os of orderprocessing"
    >
      {{os.name}}
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
</td>
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvpqp1-lvq7ye?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)